# Take photo intent returns null on data

Tags: android, file, android-gallery

I'm creating an app to take photos and delete image from gallery after specific process. Here is my code

```
  Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
  if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
      startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, requestCode);
  }
```

And I handle the result just like this

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        image1 = (Bitmap) extras.get(IMAGE_BUNDLE_NAME);
        imageView1.setImageBitmap(image1);
        imageUri1 = data.getData();
    }
}
```

The problem is that `data.getData();` returns `null` in some devices. I tried to replace `URI` with this code

```
imageUri1 = getImageUri(getActivity(), image1);
```

And this method

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

Whe I use this `Uri` I can't delete file from device. This is how I delete images

```
private void deleteFileFromMediaStore(final ContentResolver contentResolver, int requestCode) {
    String canonicalPath;
    File fdelete = new File(imageUri1.getPath());

    if(fdelete != null){
        try {
            canonicalPath = fdelete.getCanonicalPath();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            canonicalPath = fdelete.getAbsolutePath();
        }
        final Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(Constants.EXTERNAL_STORAGE_CONSTANT);
        final int result = contentResolver.delete(uri,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA + "=?", new String[] {canonicalPath});
        if (result == 0) {
            final String absolutePath = fdelete.getAbsolutePath();
            if (!absolutePath.equals(canonicalPath)) {
                contentResolver.delete(uri,
                        MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA + "=?", new String[]{absolutePath});
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I delete the photo or how can I make `data.getData()` non null on all devices?

Comment: check what `data.getAction()` returns

Comment: data.getAction() returns "inline-data"

Comment: I was facing same problem for croping image, some phones age providing path vai `getAction` method

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that data.getData(); returns null in some devices

It will return `null` with most camera apps, as it is supposed to return `null`.

> How can I delete the photo

Save the thumbnail photo to a file (`compress()` and a `FileOutputStream`).

Or, use `EXTRA_OUTPUT` to request that the camera app save a full-size photo to a location that you specify (e.g., using a `FileProvider`-supplied `Uri`).

Or, use a library like Fotoapparat to take photos directly in your app, rather than relying on one of hundreds of camera apps.

> how can I make "data.getData()" non null on all devices?

You can't.

Comment: Using `EXTRA_OUTPUT` creates two files. One is the file specified on URI, and a second one with default camera name "IMAGE_1234", when I delete the file, I'm deleting only the URI file, not the second one, is there any wy to delete both files?

Comment: @DaniGarcia: "Using EXTRA_OUTPUT creates two files" -- the particular camera app that you are using is buggy. [This is not surprising, as many camera app developers seem to avoid testing this feature](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/08/action-image-capture-fallacy.html). "is there any wy to delete both files?" -- there is no guaranteed way to do that. If you want this degree of control, stop using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` and take the photos yourself (Fotoapparat, etc.).